# Computing energy and forces directly from machine learned wavefuntion/density

Tags: basis-sets, hartree-fock, machine-learning

I have been reading up on methods where electron density was estimated directly from some machine learning method, followed by evaluation of energy and forces[1,2]. My understanding is that this is achieved by

1. predicting the wavefunction coefficients (i.e. $C_i$ in $\sum C_i G_i$, where $G_i$ is gaussian/planewave the basis set
2. computing energy and forces directly from this wavefunction/density

I was trying to replicate similar approach to better understand it, but by using simple Hartree Fock method. I tried to compute energy of such an ML determined wave function directly. However to compute the  energy of a wavefunction I needed the Fock matrix, which would need not only the determined wavefunction, but also other orbitals.

That is, the Fock matrix (Szabo and Ostlund, 3.154):

$$
F_{\mu\nu} = H_{\mu\nu} + \sum_{ij}P_{ij}(\mu\nu|ij) - 0.5 (\mu i|j\nu)
$$

requires contributions $P_{ij}$ from all orbitals.

So is similar approach impossible for HF and only feasible for DFT? Or do I need to predict the full density matrix for HF?

**References**

1. Fiedler, L., Modine, N.A., Schmerler, S. et al. Predicting electronic structures at any length scale with machine learning. npj Comput Mater 9, 115 (2023). [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41524-023-01070-z)
2. Rackers, J. A.; Tecot, L.; Geiger, M.; Smidt, T. E. Cracking the Quantum Scaling Limit with Machine Learned Electron Densities. arXiv.org. [DOI](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2201.03726)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do Hartree-Fock with densities, only. You need density matrices to evaluate exact exchange.

However, you can do semilocal density functional calculations with knowledge of the electron density, only. A commonly used way to learn the electron density is through the auxiliary basis expansion: the electron density, which reads in the atomic orbital basis as $n({\bf r}) = \sum_{\mu \nu} P_{\mu\nu} \chi_\mu({\bf r}) \chi_\nu({\bf r})$ is expressed in an auxiliary basis familiar from density fitting methods as $n({\bf r}) \approx \sum_A c_A \chi_A({\bf r})$. Machine learning (ML) is then done on the coefficients $c_A$.

Knowing the ML prediction, one can compute the Fock matrix in the orbital basis following density fitting techniques. The density functional is evaluated by quadrature on a grid, and the Coulomb matrix is computed with three-center two-electron integrals as $J_{\mu \nu} = \sum_{A}(\mu \nu|A)c_A$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, If I can just clarify a small doubt: is my interpretation of three-c two-e you mentioned correct (in terms of MMD recurrence)?   $\sum_A (ab|A) c_A = \sum_{A}c_A \sum_{|u|=0}^{l_\mu+l_\nu} (-1)^{|u|} E_{\mu\nu}^u R_{A+u}(\alpha, R_{PQ})$. Sorry if it is too much of ask or too naive on my part.

Comment: You are asking is whether the three-center integral $(ab|A)$ can be evaluated with McMurchie-Davidson as the expression you include. This is a highly technical question, unrelated to the present discussion, and I don't have an answer for you. There are many algorithms you can use to evaluate integrals; the derivation for a simplified Obara-Saika scheme for density fitting integrals was given in [doi:10.1039/b605188j](https://doi.org/10.1039/b605188j).